# How to uninstall Windows 7 and install Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I want to replace an old Windows 7 operating system on a 64 bit hp desktop with Ubuntu.

I have read the answers on this site.
Not helping me.

My Windows 7 machine had a 12.04 Ubuntu OS running as a dual boot.

A few months ago, the boot to Ubuntu failed. I have downloaded an iso of the newest Ubuntu (16.04) and run through the "`erase and install`" option, the "`LVM`" option, and the "`something else`" option to install Ubuntu. Results have all been the same.

[image]

When I pull the DVD with the iso out and reboot the machine, the dual boot option is still there, the Ubuntu boot is still dead, and Windows 7 is still alive! With all my data!

I had backed all of the Windows data files to an external hard drive formatted NTFS. That drive has been installed through a USB port. Any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: Any decent [howto](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) would be a good start.

Comment: Selecting the second option should do what you want. If that doesn't work, edit your question to include exactly what issues you faced while attempting to install Ubuntu over Windows.

Answer (score 1):

When you boot to a live disk, use the "Try Ubuntu" feature.

From there, open GParted and erase the hard drive by creating a new partition table (Use `gpt` if you have EFI, `msdos` otherwise). This will fully nuke everything off the hard drive, so make sure that you have all important data backed up.

Then, you may proceed with your install and choose whatever options you want, and there should be no way for Windows to stay alive (that is, unless it's on a different drive).

Comment: @Randal if you do not care about any data on your hard disk then you can just choose `erase disk and install ubuntu`

Comment: @Akihlish Tried that. Didn't work. Thanks.